# How do I get the module instance for a class in Python?

Tags: python

I am learning Python, and as always, I'm being ambitious with my starter projects.  I am working on a plugin system for a community site toolkit for App Engine.  My plugin superclass has a method called `install_path`.  I would like to obtain the `__path__` for the `__module__` for `self` (which in this case will be the subclass).  Problem is, `__module__` returns a `str` rather than the module instance itself.  `eval()` is unreliable and undesirable, so I need a good way of getting my hands on the actual module instance that doesn't involve `eval`ling the `str` I get back from `__module__`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`sys.modules`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.modules) dict contains all imported modules, so you can use:

```
mod = sys.modules[__module__]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about [Importing modules](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm)

> `X = __import__(‘X’)` works like `import
>   X`, with the difference that you 1)
>   pass the module name as a string, and
>   2) explicitly assign it to a variable
>   in your current namespace.

You could pass the module name (instead of 'X') and get the module instance back. Python will ensure that you don't import the same module twice, so you should get back the instance that you imported earlier.

Comment: Well, this does seem to work.  I'm kinda hoping for a cleaner solution, but if nothing else comes along, I'll accept it.

Comment: Note that if you do `__import__('foo.bar')`, it will return the `foo` module, not `foo.bar`. See the `__import__` docs for details.

Comment: Well, there are a couple of good reasons why Lukas's solution is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use the module's global [`__file__` variable](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__file__) if all you want is the module's path.